# Graffiti texture creation from image in gimp/krita

Tags: gimp, texture, krita

I want to take a black and white image and create a graffiti image out of it, as in the cover of linkin park's album "hybrid theory", and i must do this with either gimp or krita. The result will be a texture, so i don't want funky backgrounds or anything outside the graffiti in the resulting image. How could i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take your picture:

[image: Original picture]

- *Colors>Desaturate*
- *Colors>Brightness contrast* and add a lot of contrast, adjust brightness to keep enough parts of the image dark:

[image: Desaturation+brightness contrast]

- Layer>Mask>add layer mask, initialize with greyscale copy of layer and ticj the "invert mask" (you want the white to be transparent)
- Alpha-lock the layer and bucket fill with required color

[image: Final]

Comment: Was this gimp or krita?  I’m guessing gimp but you didn’t say.